# Get process running list in CSV

Tags: process, csv

Below there sample of process running list present. From that list How can we get list process running in a csv file?

```
root      94701   8609  0 Jul02 ?        00:00:01 containerd-shim -namespace system -workdir /opt/app/k8s-docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/8328929kdd -address /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock -containerd-binary /usr/bin/containerd -runtime-root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc
root      72530      1  8 Jun23 ?        21:14:22 /usr/local/bin/kubelet --logtostderr=true --v=2 --address=0.0.0.0 --node-ip=XXX.XX.XXX.XX --hostname-override=999999 --allow-privileged=true --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --authentication-token-webhook --authorization-mode=Webhook --enforce-node-allocatable=pods,kube-reserved --eviction-minimum-reclaim=memory.available=500Mi,nodefs.available=500Mi --network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin --volume-plugin-dir=/var/lib/kubelet/volume-plugins
165421    99404  99381  0 02:17 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process nginx -c /opt/att/data/conf/nginx.conf -g daemon off;
165421    99718  99404  0 02:17 ?        00:00:01 nginx: OneAgent companion process
165421    99720  99404  0 02:17 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
root     101066  61117  0 Jun29 ?        00:00:07 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir 
165421   110687 110614  0 Jun23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/stunnel /opt/ajsc/etc/config/redis/stunnel.conf
1000      43202  36182  0 Jun29 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/bin/startManagedWebLogic.sh ManagedServer
root  121802      1  3 Jun16 ?        15:47:09 /opt/app/workload/enabler/java/jdk/bin/java -Xmx16G -Xms16G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xloggc:/opt/app/workload/enabler/apache_kafka/kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9998 -javaagent:/opt/app/workload/enabler/Monitor/jmx_exporter-master/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar=8081:/opt/app/workload/enabler/Monitor/kafka-0-8-2.yml -Dkafka.logs.dir=/opt/app/workload/enabler/apache_kafka/kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0/bin/../logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:bin/../config/log4j.properties -cp :/opt/app/workload/enabler/apache_kafka/kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0/bin/../libs/jackson-annotatio-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/app/workload/enabler/apache_kafka/kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0/config/security.conf kafka.Kafka config/server.properties
```

Actually i am trying to fetch list of processes running in system.

Comment: `ps -o pid --no-header` will list one pid per line

Comment: But multiple processes running for same process then there is issue. example nginx, nginx have master process and worker process. Actually i am trying to fetch list of processes running in system.

Comment: you mean threads ? use `-L` option  to list them. ( `ps -o pid,lwp,comm  -e -L` )

Comment: Has already been asked and answered, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856201/how-to-store-ps-command-output-in-csv-format

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov you shared url is converting ps -ef result into csv. I needs list process running. I  did n't same process entry multiple times. so i will use sort and unique on urs o/p . Let me know if any solution You have.

Answer (score 0):

csv-ps from https://github.com/mslusarz/csv-nix-tools does that.

You can use other tools from this repo to filter/process csv-ps output (csv-grep, csv-cut, csv-sort, etc) and then execute a command using csv-exec.